# Coding a batch game, about using the GOTO tag

Tags: batch-file, goto

```
@echo off
:gotoONE
echo ONE
:BeginCode
set /p Choice=What is your choice?
if '%choice%' == '1' GOTO gotoONE
if '%choice%' == '2' GOTO gotoTWO
:gotoTWO
echo TWO
```

When I use this (test) code when the user types "1" from the:

```
if '%choice%' == '1' GOTO gotoONE
```

The code will goto "gotoTWO" instead of "gotoONE"

How do you make the code goto the "gotoONE" instead of just moving forward.

Comment: Wild guess: Capital letter at the start of choice?

Comment: You mean I should make it lowercase?

Comment: Your code works fine as described.  Of course it will fail if any spaces etc are included.  Enter `1` and it echoes `ONE` again.

Comment: What is happening is the check fails and it goes to the line that follows the checks - in this case gotoTWO (by default). Can you make sure what you are checking and what you are entering are indeed matching ?

Comment: foxidrive and prabindh... I'm sorry I fixed it haha. Yea, I typed the code wrong in the ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if %choice% equ 1 GOTO gotoONE
if %choice% equ 2 GOTO gotoTWO
```

If you try using this in place  of the original set of commands after the set /p Choice= it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change to stop it falling through if something else is entered.

```
goto :EOF
:gotoTWO
```